# Can we add a new custom field in contact creation form which comes as drop down

Tags: audience-manager

I want a custom field in contact creation form which comes in drop down not in text box. Because I have a requirement of a Brand custom field which should have three or four fixed choose option. If we don't have solution for this requirement then is it possible to add some default value for this custom field on publication basis. like If a contact is inserted by a certain publication then Brand value should be something or if I inserted contact from other publication then the default value should be something else. It should also be applicable for Import functionality.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to create a drop-down list field. You could use Keywords instead.